# Click event using a button ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am venturing out and learning some javascript and jquery, In my project I have a button element with an id inline. When you click the button it is suppose to fade in another div. I am missing something but since I am new to this language I am not sure what I believe the script function is correct.

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Open Radar Controls">
   <button id="play" class="map__control_icon"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
</span>
```

Thinking that since the ID above is inline with the button element maybe that was causing some conflict. So I tried the below and wrapped it in a div. I prefer the above method if it would work since it is cleaner and less code.

```
<div id="play">
   <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Open Radar Controls">
      <button class="map__control_icon"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Here is the script I am calling. I do have it in an external js file but, I am calling the file inside the document with the button. Not sure if that matters much or not. I tried the code in the header and at the end of the body with both HTML methods above and nether seemed to work. What am I missing and not doing right?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play").click(function() {
    $("#radar-control-container").fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

Might also mention I am getting now errors in the console ether.

**EDIT**

I added the mapAds div to the script and when you push the button it fades out like it is suppose to but the radar-control-container div does not fade it. So least I know it is nothing something with the button. I think it has to do with it being hidden on document ready and I need event to change that to display first then fade in maybe?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play").click(function() {
    $("#radar-control-container").delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    $("#mapAds").fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Two things, did you import jQuery? And you don't have an element with this id `radar-control-container` at least not in your example.

Comment: And a third...is that element hidden so it can be faded in?

Comment: 1.) Yes JQuery is imported. I have other scripts on this page and site that use it. 2.) I didn't include the ID radar-control_container in the example since it would have bloated the question. It does exsist though and yes it is hidden on load. Kinda, it shows when the page firsts loads then once it loads it hides. That's the next battle after this one.

Answer (score 1):

I got it sorted out with the following and it works as designed.

Added this to show it from it's hidden state...

```
.css('visibility', 'visible').
```

Then the full script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play").click(function() {
    $("#radar-control-container").css('visibility', 'visible').delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    $("#mapAds").fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

Hopefully this is correct, thanks @charlietfl for pointing me in the right direction.